# How to deploy azure webjob automatically via VS Team Services - release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I want to deploy azure webjob using **build and release management of visual studio  team services.** 
I have created a webjob project and I already deployed from visual studio and I am looking to make the deployment automatic.

Thank you!

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/18/deploying-and-schedule-azure-webjobs-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app-with-bonus-cron-scheduling/

Answer (score 8):

Refer to these steps to publish/deploy web job:

1. Open VS 2015 and create a Web Job project (e.g. WebJob1)
2. Right click the project > Publish As Azure WebJob, then it will create `webjob-publish-settings.json` file (**This is required**)
3. Create a build definition, steps:

   - NuGet Installer (Path to solution or packages.config: `**\*.sln`; Installation type: `Restore)`
   - Visual Studio Build (Solution: `**\*.sln`, MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`)
   - Publish Build Artifacts (Path to Publish: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`; Artifact Name: `drop`; Artifact Type: `Server`)
4. Queue build
5. Create a release definition and link to that build definition(Artifacts tab), tasks:
6. Azure App Service Deploy (Specify Azure Subscription and App Service name; Package or Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\WebJob1.zip`
7. Create a new release

On the other hand, to configure the Azure service endpoint, you can refer to this blog: [Automating Azure Resource Group deployment using a Service Principal in Visual Studio Online: Build/Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/).

Comment: Do you have to follow the wizard to publish?

Comment: I noticed that the publish webjob installs a nuget package called Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish and add it to the csproj as <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
  This is whats critical

Comment: If you have multiple WebJobs generated during build step, do you have to create a Release for each WebJob? Or is there a way to have one release deploy multiple webjobs...