# Building/deploying azure webjob with website copies source files instead of binaries/executable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobssdk, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've added a webjobs sdk project to my existing website.  The website runs as an azure app service.  I've always done building and deployment by queueing up a new build in visual studio online and deploying from there to my azure website.  Recently I created this webjob project in the same solution, that based on this webjobs-list.json generated and put in the website project should cause the webjob to also be deployed with the website during deployment (or so the documentation says).  What is happening though is that when it deploys, and I take a look at what is in app_data\jobs\continuous, is not the binaries and executable that I expect, it's the actual source code/project files that have been copied into there.  Obviously that isn't going to run, and it shouldn't have thrown source code out there on my website anyway.

I also had to change my release definition in visual studio online to just look for [my website project name].zip, instead of just *.zip, because otherwise I'd get an error from the release indicating: Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern. Please restrain the search patern.

...this appeared to be because the build process not only creates a zip file for my website, it also creates one for the webjobs project.  From what I understand and have read, I am supposed to change my release to just look for the website zip file and ignore the other zip file, and just let that get deployed and it should all work fine, but again, what is copied into my jobs folder on the website isn't the binaries or executable for the webjob, it's the actual source files.

How can I get this to deploy just the binaries and executable with the site instead of the source files?

The only other thing I could find to do is remove the webjobs-list.json file from the web project so they are no longer linked together, which causes the build to no longer populate app_data\jobs\continuous with my web job project source files when deployed, and to create an additional task in my release definition to grab and deploy the other zip file that is created during the build (for the webjob project, and it contains the debug files with those binaries for whatever reason).  However everything I read tells me that this is not supposed to have to be done, it should just work without me having to do this.

EDIT:

My web project is an MVC 5 project that I created with VS 2013.  The web jobs project uses the 2.0.0.0 version of the webjobs sdk.

The build and release definitions, I followed the steps in this article to create:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps

The only additional thing I did after following this article, is in my release definition, I changed the Package or Folder field to look for [my mvc web project name].zip, instead of *.zip, otherwise I'd get the error message noted above.

Comment: Are you doing DotNet classic or core?

Comment: What's the problem if you add additional step/task to deploy webjob? It works for me to deploy webjob (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112086/how-to-deploy-azure-webjob-automatically-via-vs-team-services-release)

Comment: What're detail steps you did?

Comment: Based on my test, it includes runtime files not source files (A MVC project and a webjob project, then Right click the MVC project > Add > Existing Project As Azure Job). Can you share a simple solution on the OneDrive?

Comment: Please see my edited comments above

Comment: Yes, you can't use *.zip if there are multiple files matched. What's the problem if add an additional web app deploy task to deploy web job? On the other hand, what's the result if you publish web app to web deploy package via visual studio, does the web job source file included in the app_data\jobs...? Can you share a simple solution on the OneDrive.

Comment: Note: you need to @myname in order to I can accept the notification once you replied.